# I can't update the SQLite database Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a database with different tables, till now I was updating the database without problems. but now I want to add a new row in "TABLE_ALERTAS" even I upload the database version "DATABASE_VERSION = 12" always give the error saying the row doesn't exist. I dont know what to try more.

I know for sure that when I open the app all other tables are updated.

the problem is when I add the row KEY_CODIALERTA in TABLE_ALERTAS.

Here is the code:

public class DBAdapter {

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "ID";
public static final String KEY_CODIACTIVITAT = "CODIACTIVITAT";
public static final String KEY_ACTIVITAT = "ACTIVITAT";
public static final String KEY_DATA = "DATA";
public static final String KEY_HORES = "HORES";

public static final String KEY_ROWID2 = "ID2";
public static final String KEY_nomprojecte = "NOMPROJECTE";
public static final String KEY_codictivitat = "CODIACTIVITAT";
public static final String KEY_nomctivitat = "NOMACTIVITAT";
public static final String KEY_codiprojecte = "CODIPROJECTE";

// Login table name
private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

// Login Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static final String KEY_DNI = "created_at";

// Alert table name
private static final String TABLE_ALERTAS = "alertas";

// Alert Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_TEXTALERTA = "TEXTALERTA";
private static final String KEY_DESCALERTA = "DESCALERTA";
private static final String KEY_NOMACTIVITAT = "NOMACTIVITAT";
private static final String KEY_TITOLPROJECTE = "TITOLPROJECTE";
private static final String KEY_CODIALERTA = "CODIALERTA";


public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB_Informacio";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Informacio";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "dadesPerOmplir";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 12;
public static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+DATABASE_TABLE+"("+KEY_ROWID+" integer primary key autoincrement not null, "+
        KEY_CODIACTIVITAT+" text not null, "+KEY_ACTIVITAT+" text not null, "+KEY_DATA+" text not null, "+KEY_HORES+" text not null);"; 

public static final String DATABASE_CREATE2 = "create table "+DATABASE_TABLE2+"("+KEY_ROWID2+" integer primary key autoincrement not null, "+
        KEY_nomprojecte+" text not null, "+KEY_codictivitat+" text not null, "+KEY_nomctivitat+" text not null, "+KEY_codiprojecte+" text not null);";

public static final String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE," //Es unique pq es el que utilizamos para el login "userName"
        + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_DNI + " TEXT" + ")";

public static final String CREATE_ALERT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ALERTAS + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + KEY_TEXTALERTA + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_DESCALERTA + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_NOMACTIVITAT + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_TITOLPROJECTE + " TEXT"
        + KEY_CODIALERTA + " TEXT" + ")";

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;

private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}
public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE2);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_ALERT_TABLE);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(DBAdapter.TAG, "se ha actualizado la base de datos");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE + "'");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE2 + "'");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + DBAdapter.TABLE_LOGIN + "'");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + DBAdapter.TABLE_ALERTAS + "'");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}public long insertarAlerta(String txtalerta,String txtdescalerta, String txtnomactivitat, String txtnomprojecte, String intcodialerta) 
{
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put(KEY_TEXTALERTA, txtalerta);
    valores.put(KEY_DESCALERTA, txtdescalerta);
    valores.put(KEY_NOMACTIVITAT, txtnomactivitat);         
    valores.put(KEY_TITOLPROJECTE, txtnomprojecte);
    valores.put(KEY_CODIALERTA, intcodialerta);
    return db.insert(TABLE_ALERTAS, null, valores);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. You're missing a comma.

```
public static final String CREATE_ALERT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ALERTAS + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + KEY_TEXTALERTA + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_DESCALERTA + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_NOMACTIVITAT + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_TITOLPROJECTE + " TEXT," // a comma was missing here
        + KEY_CODIALERTA + " TEXT" + ")";
```

I recommend not to catch and ignore the exception in `onCreate()`, since you will miss errors such as this which should have thrown an exception.

```
catch(SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: Sure thing. Remember, only catch & ignore an exception when you *expect* it to happens as normal behavior and you *know* what the consequences of ignoring it will be. Otherwise you have to make sure the error gets reported, it will save you a lot of debugging...